# Setting checkbox values from database using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I have a form in which i have two checkboxes (Checkbox 1 and Checkbox 2).

Now, what i want is:

1.) If only Checkbox 1 is selected while adding the details then in edit mode only Checkbox 1 should be selected. **(which is happening)**

2.) If only Checkbox 2 is selected while adding the details then in edit mode only Checkbox 2 should be selected. **(which is happening)**

3.) If both of them were selected while adding the details then in edit mode both Checkboxes should be selected. **(which is not happening)**

If someone can point me in the right direction or point my mistake that would be really great.

I have already checked many solutions for this here but none of them works for me or you can point me towards the link which i may have missed.

I will add my jquery function as well as how i am storing them in database in comma separated way.

Checkboxes:-

```
<div class = "error_placement_checkbox">
<div align = "center" class="ui inverted form" id = "idcheckbox">
    <div align = "center" class=" inline required fields">
        <label> Checkboxes </label>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                    <input type = "checkbox" name = "p_act1" value = "Checkbox_1" >
                    <label> Checkbox 1 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui checkbox">
                    <input type = "checkbox" name = "p_act2" value = "Checkbox_2" >
                        <label> Checkbox 2 </label>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My jquery function:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index)
        {   
            if ($(this).val() == "<c:out value = '${product.p_act}' />")            
            ($(this).prop('checked' , true));
        });
    });
                
</script>
```

In my Controller Servlet:-  // To store them in comma separated.

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
if (request.getParameter("p_act1") != null) { items.add (request.getParameter("p_act1")); }
if (request.getParameter("p_act2") != null) { items.add (request.getParameter("p_act2")); }
String p_act =  String.join(" , ", items);
```

Edit:-

This is my whole jquery function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index)
        {   
//  console.log(this.value);                
            if ("<c:out value = '${product.p_act}' />".split(",").includes($(this).val()))          
            ($(this).prop('checked' , true));
//  console.log(this.value);                
        });
    });
                
</script>
```

edit2:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index)
            {   
    console.log(this.value);                
                if ("11,22".split(",").includes($(this).val()))             
                ($(this).prop('checked' , true));
    console.log(this.value);                
            });
        });
                
    </script>

in console:-

(index):269 Checkbox_1
(index):272 Checkbox_1
(index):269 Checkbox_2
(index):272 Checkbox_2
```

Comment: `if ($(this).val() == "<c:out value = '${product.p_act}' />")` - you are looping over _all_ checkboxes, and check if their respective value was equal to this _one_ fixed value that you output from the server side. Since both of your checkboxes have different values, this can of course only ever be true for at most one of them.

Comment: Now is the time for you to do some debugging.  Which specific operation doesn't do what you expect?  Is the data being saved as you expect it to?  Is it being fetched from the data as you expect it to?  Is the resulting client-side code what you expect it to be?  What *specifically* isn't working?  (If you're not familiar with how to debug any of your code, take some time to work on that before trying to address this problem.  Debugging is a fundamental skill for all programming.)

Comment: @CBroe Thanks for showing the mistake. yes it's only showing one value will keep your suggestion in mind.

Comment: @David thanks for replying 1.) If both the checkboxes are selected then in edit mode none of them gets selected 2.) yes, the data is being saved as expected. 3.) Yes i am fetching the same data in array format and displaying on another jsp page to it's being displayed in array format as expected. yeah i logged the data the first and second values are showing individually but if both of them are selected then it not showing anything thanks for your suggestion will keep this in mind forever and will give more time to improve my debugging skills.

Comment: If you're seeing `if ("<c:out value = '${product.p_act}' />"` in the *rendered* output (not the source files) then your server-side is not processing the file.  If it's in a separate .js, then try moving it into a `<script>` tag inside the html file

Comment: Your issue could be that you're using `String.join(" , ", items);` - ie with `" , "` - spaces around the comma - so the split needs to match this, not just `","`.  This would be clearer if we could see the *rendered* output (as I keep saying) as it would if `if ("123 , 456").split(",")...` and it would be obvious that split would give `"123 "` (with a space on the end) which does not match `"123"` (without a space)

Comment: i removed spaces before trying the code and i tried splitting like "11,22" but in console it's not showing. i will edit how i tried doing it.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for the help !! some typing mistake. i tried logging it properly this time and got the spilt to work now i am getting the desired output thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks everyone who took out the time to guide and showed how to debug properly. i'll work more on my debugging skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When debugging js/jquery, **always use rendered code** - you'll see that you have something like:

```
if ($(this).val() == "123,456")
```

At no point, does either of your checkboxes have the value of `"123,456"`

So the `if` never works if you have both ticked as it's comparing a single value with a combined string.  You *could* compare by using `split` and checking with `includes`:

```
if ("123,456".split(",").includes($(this).val())
```

So your code would be:

```
if ("<c:out value = '${product.p_act}' />".split(",").includes($(this).val())
```

Or you could pass them to the js as an array instead of multiple join/split.

Comment: Thanks for taking out time to reply !! i tried the above solution but its still the same result, if both the checkboxes are selected its not showing both of them selected.

Comment: Can you provide the *rendered* html/js?  Edit your question to add it - specifically this part `if ($(this).val() == "<c:out value = '${product.p_act}' />")         `

Comment: sorry for replying late.. I have added my whole jquery function please take a look at it.